# jquery Autcomplete how can I always show the renderMenu regardless if there are source matches?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to add a helper to my jQuery autocomplete as follows:

```
    var thing = $("#thing").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: myarray
    })

    // Override the Render Menu
    thing.data("autocomplete")._renderMenu= function(ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
        // Adder
        ul.append( "<a class='helper'>Add <b>\"" + this.term + "\"</b> as a new item</a>")
    }
```

The problem is this HELPER only shows up when the autocomplete has at least 1 search match against the myarray. How can I make the menu always show when the user is focused?

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not append a blank value before your each statement?

Comment: Because the _renderMenu never gets called

Answer (score 1):

I think a little more monkey-patching is in order:

```
/* Override the _response function to always open the suggestions menu: */
thing.data("autocomplete")._response = function(content) {        
    if (!this.options.disabled) {
        this._trigger("open");
        content = this._normalize(content);
        this._suggest(content);
    }

    this.pending--;
    if (!this.pending) {
        this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
    }
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/eJMuf/

This should work, but I'll continue to look for a solution using the standard API.

---

Here's another solution that doesn't require quite as much open-heart surgery, but it requires more code:

```
var thing = $("#thing").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    /* Use a source function instead of the array */
    source: function(request, response) {
        var result = myArray.slice(0);
        /* Filter the array normally... */
        result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term);

        /* Add a placeholder result that we can process later */
        result.push({
            value: request.term,
            isPlaceholder: true
        });
        response(result);

    }
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", this.value);
});

var renderItem = thing.data("autocomplete")._renderItem;
/* Override the _renderItem function to display the placeholder item */
thing.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    if (item.isPlaceholder) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a class='helper'>Add <b>\"" + item.value + "\"</b> as a new item</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);

    } else {
        renderItem(ul, item);
    }
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FvCY6/

I would personally go with this solution since it is less invasive.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to add an element regardles of the number of items you get from backend.
If its a json array then add a json object with a label and a  special value of -1.In that case the array will always contain one object. :)